# How to defer a function until element available?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have content that is being dynamically generated. How to I "listen" to a selector and trigger a function when it is available, then stop listening. Is there something like this in jQuery 1.7?

Comment: Read up on the jQuery.Deferred API

Comment: @aaronfrost How does that API handle this use case at all?

Comment: The straightforward way would be to just move triggering this function to where the content is being generated. I don't think there's a current jQuery plugin to deal with DOM modification events.  You could try handling those directly I suppose.

Comment: [DOM mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents) are actually deprecated, and there has never been full support in any browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Sorry, didn't really read your question right! :)

You can do it, but it's a bit of a pain. There's no native support for it in jQuery, but browsers fire events that you can hook into. Check out the [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent) that are available and how to implement them, specifically the [DOMNodeInserted event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php). There's also some [info here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1623-Ask-Ben-Detecting-When-DOM-Elements-Have-Been-Removed-With-jQuery.htm) on how to handle the removal of an element (hooking into the DOMNodeRemoved event using jQuery). Hope this helps!

*My original, incorrect answer:*

You should be able to use the jQuery `on()` method to bind events to given elements. If the elements don't exist when the page is rendered you can bind the event to a parent element that does exist, and let jQuery "bubble up" the event through the DOM to the handler you've attached.

Here is an example taken from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). The event is bound to the `tbody` element, but it handles the click event on descendent `tr` elements, which may or may not exist when the event is bound.

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: This will let you detect when the element is clicked, not when the element is created. (Which might be a way to achieve what the OP wants, or it might not, but it's not what was asked.)